# Chatbot automation using Botim and WebdriverIO

Tags: botium-box

I am new to botium and want to do parallel testing using botium(CLI and Binding)-webdriverIO.
Any configuration in botium.json file?

Answer (score 0):

Botium CLI cannot do parallel testing itself. You would have to run it multiple times in parallel, sharing the botium.json configuration, but with a distinct set of test cases.